# FabricJS - Download image with a specified width and dynamic height

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using FabricJS on an HTML Canvas image maker project.

I'm trying to figure out how I can export images with a specified width, but have a dynamic height. The images that users create in the canvas can have varying heights, but always the same width (1080px).

I would like the download to function like this:

```
function saveImage(e) {
this.href = canvas.toDataURL({
format: "png",
quality: 0.8,
width: 1080,
height: auto
});
this.download = new Date().getTime() + ".png";
}
}
```

Unfortunately, "height: auto" does not work in this case. How can I achieve the result I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The idea is to multiply the current canvas height by the ratio of the export width to the current width, then round it to ensure your export height is an integer.

```
function saveImage(e) {
    this.href = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: "png",
        quality: 0.8,
        width: 1080,
        height: Math.round(1080 / canvas.width * canvas.height)
    });
    this.download = new Date().getTime() + ".png";
}
```